# Issue with quantile type 2

Tags: r, quantile

I don't understand the following behavior with `quantile`. With `type=2` it should average at discontinuities, but this doesn't seem to happen always. If I create a list of 100 numbers and look at the percentiles, then shouldn't I take the average at every percentile?  This behavior happens for some, but not for all (i.e. 7th percentile).

```
quantile(seq(1, 100, 1), 0.05, type=2)
# 5%
# 5.5 

quantile(seq(1, 100, 1), 0.06, type=2)
# 6%
# 6.5 

quantile(seq(1, 100, 1), 0.07, type=2)
# 7%
# 8 

quantile(seq(1, 100, 1), 0.08, type=2)
# 8%
# 8.5
```

Is this related to floating point issues?

```
100*0.06 == 6
#TRUE

100*0.07 == 7 
#FALSE

sprintf("%.20f", 100*0.07)
#"7.00000000000000088818"
```

Comment: FYI, your second code-block is related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is related to floating points as 0.07 is not exactly representable with floating points.

```
p <- seq(0, 0.1, by = 0.001)
q <- quantile(seq(1, 100, 1), p, type=2)
plot(p, q, type = "b")
abline(v = 0.07, col = "grey")
```

[image]

If you think of the quantile (type 2) as a function of p, you will never evaluate the function at exactly 0.07, hence your results.Try e.g. decreasing `by` in the above.  In that sense, the function returns exactly as expected. In practice with continuous data, I cannot imagine it would be of any consequence (but that is a poor argument I know).